# Use a custom colour scheme for ggplot contour plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, visualization, contour

I want to create a contour plot using ggplot in R. Using reproducible examples, here is a picture of what I would like to get as my result:

[image: desired plot]

As seen, I want a divergent colour scheme with the lowest values dark red, the highest values dark blue, and medium values near white.

Here is the standard code for getting what I want:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled()
```

[image: default plot]

I do not like the default colour scheme. So, I want to change the colour scheme. The standard way to do this seems to be:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = 'div', palette = 'Spectral')
```

[image: standard non-default colour palette]

Unfortunately, colours available through scale_fill_brewer do not match want I want. (There are complicated reasons for this, but I want to keep things focused. I want a custom palette.)

So, to set up a custom palette, here is the best I've been able to do so far:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(hcl.colors(8, 'Blue-Red 2')))
```

[image: desired plot]

So, that is the code that gives me exactly what I want. However, there is one BIG problem: in creating my custom colour palette with `hcl.colors(8, 'Blue-Red 2')` , I hardcoded the fact that there are exactly 8 different colours in the palette. I know this because I have tried different things and I know that for this dataset, `geom_contour_filled` creates exactly 8 contour categories. But I want to write my code flexibly (specifically, in a function) that will use different datasets for which `geom_contour_filled` will create different numbers of contour categories.

Note that if I use a palette that does not have enough different colours (e.g., 7), then the plot is buggy:

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(hcl.colors(7, 'Blue-Red 2')))

Error in `palette()`:
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 8 needed but only 7 provided.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

And if I try to use more than enough colours (e.g, 20), then the divergent colour scheme fails (I can no longer distinguish above-average from below-average values):

```
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rev(hcl.colors(20, 'Blue-Red 2')))
```

[image: too many palette colours]

So, **how can I create a contour plot in ggplot and use a custom colour palette that might have a dynamic number of different colours?** The solution I am looking for must use ggplot (for reasons beyond which I explain in this post). I would prefer to minimize the number of other packages that I would use, but if I can solve this only with another supplementary package that plays nicely with ggplot, then that would also be helpful.

Comment: Did you paste your question twice?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I think you could get there if you could supply the breaks parameter to `geom_contour_filled`.  And to quote the help file,  x and y coordinates form an equally spaced grid, and each combination of x and y appears once. Seems like the function calls `lang::list2`, if that's at all helpful.

Comment: Check out this: https://nanx.me/blog/post/ggplot2-color-interpolation/.  That might get you what you need

Comment: @markhogue Yes, I did; sorry. I've corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own special `fill` scale using `discrete_scale` with a palette function:

```r
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled() +
  discrete_scale('fill', 'RB2', palette = \(x) rev(hcl.colors(x, 'Blue-Red 2')))
```

[image]

So even if you have 20 bins, the same code will work:

```r
ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density)) +
  geom_contour_filled(bins = 20) +
  discrete_scale('fill', 'RB2', palette = \(x) rev(hcl.colors(x, 'Blue-Red 2')))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, @Allan Cameron, but can anyone tell me where to find documentation on the `\(x)` part of `palette = \(x)`? I'd just like to understand how to use it.

Comment: The syntax ```\(x)```  is just shorthand for `function(x)` @markhogue. The `palette` argument takes any function that has a single argument (the number of colors requested), and returns a vector of colors of that length.